# Android Studio not setting up new project properly

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open Android Studio I get the following errors:

[image]

On Clicking File > New > Project the following screen comes up:

[image]

This, as opposed to this:

[image]

Anyone know why this is the case:

I tried reinstalling Android Studio, no luck.

Then I tried reinstalling Android Studio, SDK and HAXM, pretty much everything I could uninstall, I tried opening new project from welcome screen... still no luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try clicking on "Enable Android support" in the first picture?

Comment: I wrote out an answer so you can accept it, I get oh-so-valuable points and maybe helpful for someone else. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click "Enable Android support" in the first picture.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>Invalidate caches/restart>Invalidate and restart.

If your problem is not resolved, try clicking on "Enable Android support".

If your problem is not resolved, try going to Android SDK Manager and install:

- Extras/Google Repository
- Extras/Android Support Repository

Restart Android Studio when install finish.

If your problem persists and you are not going to use these plugins, click on "Disable not loaded plugins".

I hope this will help you.